# Column values in a table as columns in a view

Tags: mysql, pivot, view

I have a table thus:

```
CityID     ParamName      ParamValue
------    -----------     ----------
  1       Temperature        23    
  1       Humidity           56
  2       Temperature        27
  2       Humidity           49
```

I'd like to create a view, which would like like this:

```
CityID    Temperature     Humidity
------    -----------     --------
  1          23              56
  2          27              49
```

My database engine is MySQL.

Can someone please help me define such a view? Anyhelp will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function so you will need to you a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CityId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ParamName = 'Temperature' THEN ParamValue END) Temperature,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ParamName = 'Humidity' THEN ParamValue END) Humidity
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CityId
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93f4b/1)

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
select someTable.CityID,temps.ParamValue as Temperature,Hums.ParamValue as Humidity
From SomeTable
inner join someTable temps 
On someTable.CityID = temps.CityID and temps.ParamName = 'Temperature'
inner join SomeTable hums  
On someTable.CityID = hums.CityID and hums.ParamName = 'Humidity'
```